# Problems with O_CREAT

Tags: c++, file, unix

I have this line of code:

```
int outputfd = open(charArray[a + 1], O_CREAT| O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | S_IWUSR, 0640);
```

I want the file to be opened if it exists already, and I want to be created and then opened if it doesn't. If I remove O_CREAT, then only existing files will be opened. If I leave it in, I can only create files and then open them.

How can I do both?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c++]??

Answer (score 5):

You've got `S_IWUSR` in the flags parameter, when that belongs in the open mode parameter.

On Linux (and possibly other systems, not sure how standard the values are), `S_IWUSR` has the same value as `O_EXCL`, so you're getting that behavior from `open` - i.e. will fail if the file already existed. Remove `S_IWUSR` from the flags parameter, and either leave the mode as-is or replace it with the `S_IWUSR` if that's the mode you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your trouble is the exist file should be truncate after it is opened. Maybe you can remove O_TRUNC and try again.